# Splitting a number in R

Tags: r

In `R` I have a number, say `1293828893`, called `x`.

I wish to split this number so as to remove the middle 4 digits `3828` and return them, pseudocode is as follows:

```
splitnum <- function(number){
     #check number is 10 digits
     if(nchar(number) != 10){
          stop("number not of right size");
     }
     middlebits <- middle 4 digits of number
     return(middlebits);
}
```

This is a pretty simple question but the only solutions I have found apply to character strings, rather than numeric ones.

If of interest, I am trying to create an implementation in `R` of the [Middle-square method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_square_method), but this step is particularly tricky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use integer division:

```
> x <- 1293828893
> (x %/% 1e3) %% 1e4
[1] 3828
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `substr()`. See its help page `?substr`. In your function I would do:

```
splitnum <- function(number){
    #check number is 10 digits
    stopifnot(nchar(number) == 10)
    as.numeric(substr(number, start = 4, stop = 7))
}
```

which gives:

```
> splitnum(1293828893)
[1] 3828
```

Remove the `as.numeric(....)` wrapping on the last line you want the digits as a string.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a function that completely avoids converting the number to a character

```
splitnum <- function(number){
     #check number is 10 digits
     if(trunc(log10(X))!=9) {
          stop("number not of right size")
     }
     (number %/% 1e3) %% 1e4
}

splitnum(1293828893)
# [1] 3828
```